# How to move object properties inside an array with map

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how I can get a property of an object to the main array with map?

something like in the example that I put here below, in this case I want to obtain the code of the course only and change the name of the key so that instead of Code it is CourseCode

```
let arrayData = [
{
   Id: 1,
   Name: 'test1',
   CourseId: 23,
   Courses: {
      Id: 23,
      Code: 'MAT01',
      Name: 'Course1'
   }
},
{
   Id: 2,
   Name: 'test2',
   CourseId: 24,
   Courses: {
      Id: 24,
      Code: 'MAT02',
      Name: 'Course2'
   }
}]
```

RESULT:

```
let arrayData = [
{
   Id: 1,
   Name: 'test1',
   CourseId: 23,
   CourseCode: 'MAT01',
   Courses: {
      Id: 23,
      Code: 'MAT01',
      Name: 'Course1'
   }
},
{
   Id: 2,
   Name: 'test2',
   CourseId: 24,
   CourseCode: 'MAT02',
   Courses: {
      Id: 24,
      Code: 'MAT02',
      Name: 'Course2'
   }
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to use `.map()` it maps data to whatever shape you want, for your case you just need to slightly modify the original elements so the `.map()` is suitable for this situation.

Learn about [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=de)

Here I have implemented a solution:

```js
let arrayData = [{
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'test1',
    CourseId: 23,
    Courses: {
      Id: 23,
      Code: 'MAT01',
      Name: 'Course1'
    }
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    Name: 'test2',
    CourseId: 24,
    Courses: {
      Id: 24,
      Code: 'MAT02',
      Name: 'Course2'
    }
  }
];

const modifiedArray = arrayData.map((data) => {
  const {
    Courses
  } = data;
  return {
    ...data,
    CourseCode: Courses.Code
  };
});
console.log(modifiedArray);
```

Hope it helps, cheers!